# How to get the current color of navigation/status bar in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[Android]

Is there any way I can read the current color and style information from the statusbar and navigationbar and save it to a variable?

I have no problems changing the statusbar and navigationbar values using SystemChrome, however I would like to save the current color settings to restore them when I return from a screen I navigated to.

```
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.green,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.purple,
    )
);
```

I have no success with the commands below:

```
print('+++ ${SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.statusBarColor}');
print('+++ ${SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.systemNavigationBarColor}');
print('+++ ${SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.statusBarColor}');
print('+++ ${SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.systemNavigationBarColor}');
```